# Python - Copy attributes of an element and paste on another text file

Tags: python, xml, canvas, text

I have an xml file which goes like this

```
<xml>
  <canvas id="123">
      <child name="somechild" id="1"/>
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="124">
      <child name="somechild" id="2"/>
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="125">
      <child name="somechild" id="3"/>
  </canvas>
</xml>
```

I want to copy the value of the attribute id of canvas
which is basically whats inside `<canvas id="COPY THIS VALUE">`
and write them on a new text file which will list all of them like this:

```
123, 1234, 214334, 34234, 34234
```

thank you for the help!

edit---------

so far i have tried this which i saw from another answer, but it copies the whole line of canvas id instead of only whats inside the id

```
with open('file.xml') as myfile, open('fileids.xml', 'w') as outfile:
content = myfile.read()
text = re.search(r'canvas id=".*?">', content, re.DOTALL).group()
outfile.write(text)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to help you parse the document

Comment: You should never attempt to parse a structured format like XML with regular expressions. Use a parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `xml.etree.ElementTree` module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring('''<xml>
  <canvas id="123">
      <child name="somechild" id="1"/>
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="124">
      <child name="somechild" id="2"/>
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="125">
      <child name="somechild" id="3"/>
  </canvas>
</xml>''')
print([node.attrib['id'] for node in xml.findall('.//canvas')])
```

This outputs:

```
['123', '124', '125']
```

With the list you can then easily write the items to a file.

Comment: how can I use etree when I have to get the xml from a file? I tried parse but it gives back an error. - NEVERMIND! it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is your friend

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = BeautifulSoup("""<xml>
  <canvas id="123">
      <child name="somechild" id="1"/>
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="124">
      <child name="somechild" id="2"/>
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="125">
      <child name="somechild" id="3"/>
  </canvas>
</xml>""")

#writing ids to file

file = open('test.txt','w')    
for d in data.find_all('canvas'):
    file.write(d.get('id'))
    file.write('\n')
    print(d.get('id'))
file.close()
```

Output

```
123
124
125
```